# How to place three buttons in centre side by side with spacing using autolayout in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xcode8

I'm placing the three buttons side by side with spacing in the centre of the `iOS` window. I'm using `auto layout` but the `constraints` which I'm setting is:

1. I put first button to the button in `left with leading` and `top spacing with horizontal spacing` to second button.
2. I put second button with `spacing horizontally` from first button and `top spacing`
3. I put a third button with `trailing space` and `top vertical space` and `horizontal spacing` with second button
4. Next I assigned `equal widths` to all the buttons

**But still my buttons are getting misplaced why? Any Idea?**

[image: First Button]

[image: Second Button]

[image: Third Button]

Comment: upload a screenshot with constraints for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first put the 3 buttons on the screen and place them accordingly. Since you want the 3 buttons in the centre, put like this.

1)put the first button towards the left side, the 2nd button in the middle(you can see the blue cross line when you reach the middle), then the 3rd button towards right of it.

2)now select the middle button and choose the 3rd small icon from right at the bottom right (two rectangles placed parallel) and tick horizontal in container and vertical in container.

3) now select the 1st button and choose the 2nd small icon from the bottom right(one square box between 2 lines) and select the red line towards the left(there will be 4 red lines on towards side).remember to uncheck the constrain to margins. After that again select the first button and cntrl drag towards the middle button and choose centre vertically from the drag down menu

4)similarly do for the third button at the right,only difference choose the red line towards right.

hope i have explained slowly. I am also a beginner so i can understand how you feel :) Hope it helps. do ask if you got any doubts. cheers

Comment: Still facing the problem

Comment: hey, no worries, saw your screenshot just now. It is because you have changed the height and width of the button, so you have to make a few more changes. I hope you have done till now. now choose the middle button and then the 2nd small icon from right at the bottom right(square in middle of 2 lines)  and check equal and height boxes. now you can see yellow lines . at the left side of the screen you can see a yellow triangle warning like sign , select that and a pop up will come, in that select update constraints. Do this for the remaining 2 buttons.

Comment: Thanks I may be needing your help in future to learn auto layout

Comment: check means check the boxes.(put tick) :)

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: sorry, check width and height boxes.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Add all 3 button in another parent UIView.

Then add following constraints to each button.

Left Button : Top, Leading, Bottom and Equal width.
Middle Button: Top, Bottom, Equal width and Horizontally center.
Right Button : Top, Trailing, Bottom and Equal width.

Or If your deployment target is > 9.0, try using Horizontal UIStackView

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve it:

1. Set `Width` & `Height` of all three buttons.
2. Centrally align Middle Button `Horizontally` & `Vertically` to container.
3. Set `Trailing` & '`Center Vertically(Y)` of the Left-most Button to the Middle Button.
4. Set `Leading` & `Center Vertically(Y)` of the Right-most Button to the Middle Button.

Or the short way:

1. Add all three button into one Stack View.
2. Center Stack View `Vertically` and `Horizontally` to the Container.
3. Set Stack View `Spacing` value for distance between these buttons.

Comment: Lemme check and approve your answer.. You sound amazing!!

Comment: please explain 3rd and 4th point .... Do you mean Leading in 3rd point and trailing in 4th point?

Comment: **3.** The `trailing` space of first button will be attached to the middle button. AND center first button vertically to the middle button.  **4.**   The `leading` space of first button will be attached to the middle button. AND center third button vertically to the middle button.

Comment: ouhh But how to set that trailing space?? Do you mean horizontal spacing?

Comment: So what about first point ... Do you meant to set width and height in the right side bar or to set height and width constraints?

Comment: with constraints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134586/discussion-between-jessica-root-and-mr-bista).

Answer (score 1):

Set Constraints like:

Middle button : horizontally in container , equal width , height

Left button : leading , trailing, equal width and height to middle button

Right button : leading , trailing, equal width and height to middle button

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First select all the views , take into horizontally middle. Now will start constraint - Select view1 - give constraint leading ,top, horizontally spacing to view2 and give your height.

[image]
For second view - Now select all the views go to allign option right side down select the top edges. Now select only second view - give horizontal spacing to third view and height for second view.

For third view - only give constraint to trailing and height.

Last constraint - Select all the views go to pin option and select equal widths. Now your design is ready for perfect.